# How do I use get task for mailboxes in systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

I want to use get task of a mailbox, the mailbox contains data of a class Transaction type. While accessing do I need to make an object of variable tr or just a handle is sufficient to access the data received from mailbox?

> mailbox #(transaction) gentodriver;
> transaction tr;
> gentodriver.get(tr);

Would this work or do I need to create an object of tr using

> tr=new();

Comment: actually the original code is quite big , i wanted an answer that you might know  conceptually, so does .get return a pointer type that i need to store in a handle or it returns a value to be stored in object?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific to mailboxes. SystemVerilog uses *handles* to class objects, you never refer to class objects directly. Class handles are stored in class variables.

When you use the `mailbox::put()` and `get()` methods, you are making assignments from or to the arguments of those methods. You are putting a handle to the object into the mailbox, and they getting the handle. You are not copying the object, just copying the handle to it into another class variable.

Comment: So it's like i'm just sending the pointer and not the object itself , so if i use the handle and make changes in the object's properties in the receiving class, they would get reflected in the sending class' object properties too right? if yes then ig this is shallow copy, if it is then is there any way to deep copy?
Also for the above code to use in the receiving class, i just need to declare the handle and use .get with it and no need to use new() on it right?

Comment: It's not a shallow or deep copy of the object, only it's handle. There's no need to use new() and construct another copy of the object (known as a _clone_) unless you need to make modification to the object that you down't want others with a copy of the handle to see.